# Weird problems configuring network in virtualbox Ubuntu 14 guest (Windows XP host)

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I am having some strange problems trying to get a network interface working correctly in an Ubuntu 14 guest on a Windows XP host. Network connection 1 is NAT and works correctly. Network connection 2 (which I'm having trouble with) is bridged. I have tried switching the connections and having only bridged, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

What I would like to end up with is a static IP address. So far, I have been able to get a DHCP IP address working, but only under some strange circumstances.

After I boot up, I get an IP6 address (I think), but I have to `ifdown eth1` and then `dhclient eth1` in order to get an IP4 IP address allocated.

After booting, the `eth1` section of ifconfig looks like this:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:6a:a8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:6aa8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10036 (10.0 KB)  TX bytes:9540 (9.5 KB)
```

After `ifdown eth1` and then `dhclient eth1` it looks like this:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:6a:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.116  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:6aa8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:45763 (45.7 KB)  TX bytes:30797 (30.7 KB)
```

At this point, I am able to reach the server on IP 192.168.1.116 as expected.

After that, if I try `ifdown eth1` it says `ifdown: interface eth1 not configured`

In `/etc/network/interfaces` the `eth1` entry looks like this:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

If I try to make it static, in `/etc/network/interfaces` the `eth1` entry looks like this:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.46
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

After booting, the `eth1` section of ifconfig looks like this:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:6a:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.1.46  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:6aa8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:195 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19514 (19.5 KB)  TX bytes:2268 (2.2 KB)
```

However I am unable to reach the server on the static IP address.

I have no idea what to do next! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration for the static IP is correct, except you are missing a dns. You should add to the stanza `auto eth1` and so on the statement

```
              dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

or whatever you use for a DNS.

Also, you should remember that, since you have setup a `static` IP address, there is no way your gateway, DNS servers and other machines on the network can posisbly know the Ubuntu machine's name, so that you can only reach it via its IP address. CHanging this depends on how you do DNS resolution on your LAN.

Comment: I am trying to reach the server by IP address only, not by name, so DNS shouldn't matter. I added the nameservers, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @FrustratedLinuxUser Can you please post the routing table of the Ubuntu VM? Please use `ip route show`, thanks